# Interactively change color of points in traces in R plotly

Tags: r, plotly

I want to create an interactive plotly 3d scatter with markers and lines in R. The graphic should be able to highlight individual traces, which is working. It should also be able to change the color according to other variables.

Here is an example of what I want to do, the highlighting works fine, changing the color does not work:

```
library(plotly)
irs <- data.table(iris)
setkey(irs, `Species`)
p <- plot_ly(type = "scatter3d", mode = "lines+markers")
for (i in levels(irs$Species)) {
  xx <- irs[i]$Sepal.Length
  yy <- irs[i]$Sepal.Width
  zz <- irs[i]$Petal.Length
  cc <- irs[i]$Petal.Width
  p <- p %>% add_trace(x = xx, y = yy, z = zz, color = cc)
}
p <- p %>%
  layout(
    updatemenus = list(
      ## set opacity per trace to highlight a single trace
      list(y = 0.6,
           buttons = lapply(
             levels(irs$Species),
             function (x) {
               list(method = "restyle",
                    args = list("opacity",
                                ifelse(levels(irs$Species) == x,
                                       1, 0.1)),
                    label = x)
             })),
      ##  try to set different colors for points inside traces
      ## NOT WORKING
      list(y = 0.4,
           buttons = lapply(
             names(irs),
             function(x) {
               list(
                 method = "restyle",
                 args = list(
                   "color",
                   split(irs[[x]], irs$Species)
                 ),
                 label = x
               )
             }))
    )
  )
p
```

Answer (score 2):

The following code solves only a small part of your problem: how to change colors of markers and lines for a single series.
I did not find a solution for the case with multiple series.
In addition, I did not find a way for an automatic rescaling of the color map after changing the color variable from the menu. Hence, I rescaled "by hand" all variables between 1 and 3.
I realise that this is a small contribution to the solution of the problem. Anyway, I hope it can help you.

```
library(plotly)

library(scales)
irs <- iris
irs[,1:4] <- apply(irs[,1:4],2, rescale, to=c(1,3))

p <- plot_ly(data = irs, type = "scatter3d", mode = "lines+markers")
p <- p %>% add_trace(x=~Sepal.Length, y=~Sepal.Width, 
                  z=~Petal.Length, color=~Petal.Width)

p <- p %>%
  layout(
    updatemenus = list(
      list(y = 0.4,
           buttons = lapply(
             names(irs),
             function(x) {
               cols <- as.numeric(irs[,x])
               list(
                 method = "restyle",
                 label = x,
                 args = list(
                  list(marker.color=list(cols),
                       line.color=list(cols), autocolorscale=TRUE)
                 )
               )
             }))
    )
  )
p
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, it seems to be possible in javascript: https://codepen.io/etpinard/pen/pgbPag I did my best to reproduce this in R, but failed so far.

Comment: I also found out that you can use a matrix to change the color of various traces with something like this: `args=list(list(marker.color=matrix(...)), 1:n_traces)`. I haven't tried, what happens if the traces have different number of points.

Comment: btw I solved it by exporting my R data to JSON and doing everything in javascript, the resulting webpage is also much more performant than the one generated by R.

Comment: @gdkrmr Thank you for sharing your experience! Is it possibile to have the link to your interactive graph?

Comment: it's not ready yet, but I will be happy to post a link here as soon as it is ready (and given I remember to actually do it ;-) )